# ive been making a app in xcode 5.1.1 but i updated to xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode

i have been creating a app in xcode 5.1.1 for a while now ios 7.1, now that i have updated xcode to 6, do i continue as normal or should i need to do something in order to keep developing correctly? Or should i need to downgrade back to 5.1.1?

I ran the app in xcode 6 and it runs perfectly fine so far. 
I also went into the build settings to see the deployment target which is 7.1

so does this mean i can only release to 7.1?

thanks, 
for the help, appreciate it a lot.

Comment: The "Deployment Target" simply defines how far back you support. The "Base SDK" defines the APIs you can use. Generally, an app can run under any version of iOS >= the deployment target.

Comment: so my "Deployment" is 7.1 and my "Base SDK" is 8.1
This means if i publish app, will it run devices that have 7.1 or later?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Acey I tried dragging over UIVistualEffectBlur and i got a error of not being able to use in prior to ios8, so do i have to change my deployment to 8.1?

Comment: If you want to use any classes or methods from versions of iOS later than 7.1, you need to do so conditionally. Usually checking if the class responds to the newly provided selector works. UIEffectView is entirely iOS 8 so if you need to use that class, you will need to check for its existence with NSClassFromString(UIBlurEffect).

Comment: @Acey dont really get that, so i cant just change my deployment target to 8.1? i did it and i dont get the error anymore.

Comment: You can totally do that. Only iOS 8.1 and later users will be able to download your app though. I personally always like to start new projects with the latest deployment target so I get to use all of the fun new features. Keep it at 8.1 and have at it!

Comment: @Acey thanks bro! appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at @Acey 's answers, he put them perfect.